# How to access the another system mysql database through java program?

Tags: java, mysql, odbc

How to access the  another system mysql database through java program?Am using the following program but i have get the communication error?what are the changes are need to connect the another system mysql database?

```
  Public void dbconnection() {

            String name = "";
            String port = "3306";
            String user = "system";
            String pass = "system";
            String dbname = "cascade_demo";
            String host="192.168.1.61";

            try {

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                  String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+  port + "/" + dbname;
                System.out.println("URL:" + url);
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                String qry2 = "select * from item_master";
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry2);
                while (rs.next()) {

                    name = rs.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("Name:" + name);

                }


                rs.close();
                st.close();
                con.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy now i did not get any error message but the connection string i have given was not connected

Comment: Did u check the connectivity between your machine and the MySQL database machine ? Are you able to connect using the same credentials via Mysql client from your machine ?

Comment: if i use localhost on that host place i access my data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating an instance of the driver class:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

[update: not necessary after all, ignore that]

And you're also referencing "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver", is that necessary? If so, shouldn't you instantiate it also? [update: probably not]

If it works with localhost, and not with the IP specified, you need to configure mysql to listen on all ports.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat dbconnection.java; javac dbconnection.java; sudo java -cp .:/usr/share/maven-repo/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.16/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar  dbconnection
import java.sql.*;
public class dbconnection {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  String name = "";
  String port = "3306";
  String user = "root";
  String pass = "";
  String dbname = "imagetagging";
  String host="127.0.0.1";
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+  port + "/" + dbname;
   System.out.println("URL:" + url);
   //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
   String qry2 = "select * from taggers";
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry2);
   while (rs.next()) {
    name = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println("Name:" + name);
   }
   rs.close();
   st.close();
   con.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
  }
 }
}
URL:jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/imagetagging
Name:1
Name:2
Name:3
Name:4
Name:5
Name:6
Name:7
Name:8
Name:9
Name:10
Name:11
Name:12
Name:13
Name:14
Name:15
Name:16
Name:17
Name:18
Name:19
Name:20
Name:21
```

Comment: if i give like this Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); ,still am not access the database.

Comment: can you connect to the database with the mysql commandline client, using the same credentials?

Comment: If i use the above program ,the program access my database value ,it doesn't access the another system database

Comment: you need to put the other system's IP or hostname in there, and you need to *set the other system's my.cnf to listen on all interfaces* as I specified before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7724/discussion-between-javalearner-and-jcomeau-ictx)

Comment: no thanks, just set bind-address=0.0.0.0 in my.cnf on the remote machine and you should be all set

Comment: how to set bind address in my.cnf?

Comment: do you know how to use an editor, like vi or emacs? or pico or nano?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you just need to specify another connection string, with another host and other credentials, e.g.:

```
        ...
        String port = "3306";
        String user = "user_name";
        String pass = "password";
        String dbname = "db_name";
        String host="host_name";
        ...
```

Comment: why i need another connection string?

Comment: If you want to connect to another MySQL server or use different options (e.g. database name, user, password, port, etc.),  then you need to specify this in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 3(with 4th step optional) simple things to connect to  your remote mysql database server.

1. Open up any GUI tool for mysql database management (your IDE, Mysql Workbench or smth else), check if you can connect to your database by specifying your credentials, host, port and database name.
   If that succeeds you know there is nothing wrong on the db part (go to 3), if not, and you are sure you do everything correctly up to this point go to point 2.
2. check out this post on [how to enable remote access to your db](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) and try again (go to pkt 1)
3. You would have to clean up a bit your code, have a look into simple and to the point tutorial on how to connect and execute simple sql statements with java on [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)
4. Once everything is working correctly, remember to give +1 on Vogella tutorial, praise the cybercity or any other website for the explanation on how to enable remote access on you db and don't forget to come back to stackoverflow and reward all good answers :)